# Objective C eqivalent Swift code?

Tags: objective-c, swift, block, class-method, alamofire

This is a class method and I am passing block as one of the argument So basically how pass blocks in swift?

```
+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)getAllSongIfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *songInfos, NSError *error))block;
```

Comment: If only there was some sort of global search engine that would allow you to ask questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift equivalent:

```
func getAllSongIfo(userInfo: NSDictionary, withBlock block:((NSArray?, NSError?) -> Void)) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

If you want a class method you need to add the `class` keyword like:

```
class func getAllSongIfo(userInfo: NSDictionary, withBlock block:((NSArray?, NSError?) -> Void)) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```